# Why do I see a lot of weird characters when I open certain files comprising native applications

Tags: notepad, characters

I tried to open a file (QBWebConnector [which has no file extension]) in notepad but only saw this:

MZ       ÿÿ  ¸       @                                   €   º ´  Í!¸LÍ!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.

$       PE  L A˜I        à   P         ¾m      €                                À    ¹H  @                           dm W    € È           € (                                                                          H           .text   ÄM      P                   `.rsrc   È   €`               @  @.reloc            p             @  B

And about 50 other pages of garbage plus some human readable stuff that wasn't formatted correctly. Apparently that happened because this code is already compiled but how can I either open this so that I can see the code that the original developer wrote or the source code that I should be working with to modify this app (it's open source).

Comment: Because they aren't text files?  Of course its also not "garbage".

Comment: @Ramhound Please don't downvote an honest question, especially when you can't answer it.

Comment: You explained in your question that it looks that way because it is already compiled.  If you want to see the source code, that will be a different file.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, excuse me. I thought that was you. Actually it looks like somebody's just coming through and downvoting everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened a binary as a text document. Your word processor then tries to render the assembled code as binary, which Doesn't Really Work (that is to say, it SUCCEEDS, but it's nothing usable to the user).

In order to get to the source code, you'll have to track it down on the web wherever you got your QBWebConnector from. A quick google search turned up a couple resources for you:

http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_vbdotnet in Visual Basic
http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php in PHP
http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector overview

Good luck!